# un-slicing numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Given a sliced numpy array as follows:

```
b = [a[..., i] for i in a.shape[-1]]
```

What is the most simple way I can recreate `a` from `b`?

Something like:

```
for i in range(a.shape[-1]):
    c[..., i] = b[i]
```

Comment: instead of iterating through all columns with `for`, you could as well just use `b = a[..., :]` .

Comment: Do you mean `for i in range(a.shape[-1])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that list comprehension, your original operation should have been

```
b = numpy.rollaxis(a, axis=-1)
```

which produces a view of `a` as a new array instead of a list of arrays.

The reverse operation is

```
c = numpy.rollaxis(b, axis=0, start=b.ndim)
```